# What is the use of Subscribe and Unsubscribe commands in Imap4req1?

Tags: imap

What is the use of Subscribe and Unsubscribe  commands in Imap4req1? I checked RFC 3501,  but i could not understand its use. What will happen when i write following commands

```
A SUBSCRIBE "MAILBOX_NAME"

A UNSUBSCRIBE "MAILBOX_NAME"
```

will server treat those mailboxes as separate one?

Sample :

please check below once, and tell the difference

```
A LIST "" "*"
* LIST (\HasNoChildren) "/" "Bulk Mail"
* LIST (\HasNoChildren) "/" "Draft"
* LIST (\HasNoChildren) "/" "Inbox"
* LIST (\HasNoChildren) "/" "Sent"
* LIST (\HasNoChildren) "/" "Trash"
A OK LIST completed
A SUBSCRIBE INBOX
A OK SUBSCRIBE completed
A LSUB "" "*"
* LSUB (\HasNoChildren) "/" "Bulk Mail"
* LSUB (\HasNoChildren) "/" "Draft"
* LSUB (\HasNoChildren) "/" "Inbox"
* LSUB (\HasNoChildren) "/" "Sent"
* LSUB (\HasNoChildren) "/" "Trash"
A OK LSUB completed
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They change the output of the `LSUB` command. That's it.  `SUBSCRIBE` adds folders to the output of the `LSUB` command.  `UNSUBSCRIBE` will remove them from the output of the `LSUB` command.  That is, `LSUB` shows only subscribed folders.

`LIST` will always show all folders.

For example starting with all folders subscribed:

```
a LIST "" *
* LIST (\HasNoChildren) "." "INBOX.Drafts"
* LIST (\HasNoChildren) "." "INBOX.Sent"
* LIST (\HasNoChildren) "." "INBOX.Trash"
* LIST (\Marked \HasChildren) "." "INBOX"
a OK LIST completed

a LSUB "" *
* LSUB (\Marked \HasChildren) "." "INBOX"
* LSUB (\HasNoChildren) "." "INBOX.Drafts"
* LSUB (\HasNoChildren) "." "INBOX.Sent"
* LSUB (\HasNoChildren) "." "INBOX.Trash"
a OK LSUB completed
```

Now let's unsubscribe `INBOX.Sent`:

```
a UNSUBSCRIBE INBOX.Sent
a OK Folder unsubscribed.
a LSUB "" *
* LSUB (\Marked \HasChildren) "." "INBOX"
* LSUB (\HasNoChildren) "." "INBOX.Drafts"
* LSUB (\HasNoChildren) "." "INBOX.Trash"
a OK LSUB completed
```

All that's different is that `INBOX.Sent` has been removed from the LSUB output.  Note that LIST output will not have been affected at all.

Now let's put it back:

```
a SUBSCRIBE INBOX.Sent
a OK Folder subscribed.
a LSUB "" *
* LSUB (\HasNoChildren) "." "INBOX.Sent"
* LSUB (\Marked \HasChildren) "." "INBOX"
* LSUB (\HasNoChildren) "." "INBOX.Drafts"
* LSUB (\HasNoChildren) "." "INBOX.Trash"
a OK LSUB completed
```

They are generally used for a client to mark folders the user is interested in seeing.